# How to make visual studio always view commit details in a new tab in git changes?

Tags: visual-studio, team-explorer

It opens commit details in a small window inside git history and it's very inconvenient, because it's too small to see anything. Clicking "open in a new tab" every time is annoying. Is there a way to make visual studio always open it in a new tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to open Commit Details straight to a new tab.  This is feedback that we've heard a few times since we built the Git Repository window and embedded the commit details, so it is on our radar to improve the window handling in a future update.