# Visual Studio 2022: How to disable the New feature(3 windows) of Git repository?

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In the previous VS version(like 2019), when I double click a commit history at "Git Repository" tab, one new tab will be started to show the detail of this commit.
But in the current 2022 version, a "commit xxxxxx" will occupy half bottom space of "Git Repository" tab, which is advertised by Microsoft as a new feature[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-browse-repository?view=vs-2022). I have to click one more time to start a new fullscreen tab. This tiny window is totally bad because it can only hold a little code info and the bottom scroller bar is small beyond my bear, especially unacceptable for a 1080P screen.
How can I disable this function?

Answer (score 1):

That was already [reported in Sept. 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69378782/6309) and is on Visual Studio team's "radar".

But... it is not implemented yet. As far as I know, there is no setting yet to disable that "feature".